# Not getting all fields in Django form to enter the details

Tags: python, django

I wanted to use my two models - farmer (foreign key for tractor) and tractor - in a single form but I am not getting the fields of tractor in web page to enter its value I am only getting fields of farmer.

My models.py

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    email_address = models.EmailField()

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()


class Post(models.Model):
    tractor_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=150)
    implementation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True, null=True,blank=True)
    tractor_company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tractor_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add =True)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(
        Farmer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="posts")
```

my view.py Only add_post function

```
  
def add_post(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        farmer_form = FarmerForm(request.POST)
        post_form = Post(request.POST)
        if(farmer_form.is_valid() and post_form.is_valid()):
            farmer = farmer_form.save()
            post = post_form.save(False) 
            post.farmer = farmer    
            post.save()
            return redirect(reverse("tractor.views.posts"))
    else:
        farmer_form = FarmerForm()
        post_form = Post(request.POST)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args["farmer_form"] = farmer_form
    args["post_form"] =post_form
    return render(request,"tractor/form.html",args)
```

forms.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form
    method="POST"
    style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 100px"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="{% url 'tractor:add_post' %}"
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {{post_form}}
    {{farmer_form}}
    >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("tractor_price","implementation","purchase_date","tractor_company","tractor_model","description")

class FarmerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Farmer
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','phone','address','email_address')
```

I am also added the image of the form which
also the form is properly aligned as you can see in the screenshot and I am not getting the fields of tractor the form, only getting input of farmer form.

[Page I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkss6.png)

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did this: `args["tractor_form"]=post_form`, but you forgot to use  `{{tractor_form}}` in your html file.

Change `args["tractor_form"]=post_form` to `args["post_form"]=post_form`
OR
Change `{{post_form}}` in html file to `{{tractor_form}}`

**EDIT**

You don't need to do like this: `farmer_form = FarmerForm(request.POST)` in your `else` block.

```
farmer_form = FarmerForm(request.POST) # before
farmer_form = FarmerForm() # after.
```

**EDIT2**

You shouldn't put `{{post_form}}`, `{{farmer_form}}`, and `{% csrf_token %}` inside `<>` of the form tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form
    method="POST"
    style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 100px"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="{% url 'tractor:add_post' %}"
    >     <- this is where the form <> is finished.
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {{post_form}}
    {{farmer_form}}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah i did but same result, its not working.

Comment: No still not working after using the FarmerForm() the layout of the formed has change its showing form in horizontally instead of vertically

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: And please update your new code.

Comment: error is coming but after submitting I am getting==> error 'Post' object has no attribute 'is_valid'

Comment: Are you able to see the forms, right? The error occurs after you click the submit button, right?

Comment: I think you need to change 'post_form = Post(request.POST)' to 'post_form = PostForm(request.POST)'

Comment: i changed to PostForm but still not working and yes i am able to see the form and the error is after submitting the form but the main problem is that i am not able to see the input fields of PostForm  please look at the ss i have used